# Cross site AJAX without JSONP?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

Is there any way to do a cross site AJAX request without requiring JSONP?

In my situation, I need  to pull data from a third-party resource, however it is not formatted as JSON (is XML)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need some proxy server side script. You make the request to your local server, which in turn will fetch it from a remote location.

The best explanation and the solutions can be found here:
http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Here's a php example from Yahoo:
http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/samples/proxy/php_proxy_simple.txt

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use CORS: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/. It doesnt work in IE7 and Opera today. And lacks some features in IE8 ( http://caniuse.com/#search=CORS)

Comment: Support in IE is only partial, and only in IE 8 and later (many people still consider IE7 to be a major browser). Opera doesn't support it yet.